# Python: read mixed float and string csv file

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point

I have a csv file with mixed floats, a string and an integer, the formatted output from a FORTRAN file.
A typical line looks like:

```
 507.930    ,  24.4097    ,   1.0253E-04, O  III   ,    4
```

I want to read it while keeping the float decimal places unmodified, and check to see if the first entry in each line is present is another list.

Using loadtxt and genfromtxt results in the demical places changing from 3 (or 4) to 12.

How should I tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep precision exactly, you need to use the [`decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html). Otherwise, [issues with floating point arithmetic limitations](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) might trip you up.

Chances are, though, that you don't really need that precision - just make sure you don't compare `float`s for equality exactly but always allow a fudge factor, and format the output to a limited number of significant digits:

```
# instead of if float1==float2:, use this:
if abs(float1-float2) <= sys.float_info.epsilon: 
    print "equal"
```

Answer (score 1):

`loadtxt` appears to take a `converters` argument so something like:

```
from decimal import Decimal
numpy.loadtxt(..., converters={0: Decimal,
                               1: Decimal,
                               2: Decimal})
```

Should work.

`Decimal`'s should work with whatever precision you require although if you're doing significant number crunching with `Decimal` it will be considerably slower than working with `float`.  However, I assume you're just looking to transform the data without losing any precision so this should be fine.

Comment: Actually, after a closer look at the `numpy.loadtxt` this likely won't work as apparently the `converters` functions need to return a float.  Of course you could write a function yourself that attempts to preserve the precision from the input but I think the conversion to float requirement is going to make this hard to work around.

Answer (score 0):

I finished up writing some string processing code. Not elegant but it works:

```
stuff=loadtxt(fname1,skiprows=35,dtype="f10,f10,e10,S10,i1",delimiter=','‌​) 
stuff2 = loadtxt('keylines.txt') # a list of the reference values
... # open file for writing etc
for i in range(0,len(stuff)): 
    bb=round(float(stuff[i][0]),3) # gets number back to correct decimal format
    cc=round(float(stuff[i][1]),5) # ditto
    dd=float(stuff[i][2]) 
    ee=stuff[i][3].replace(" ","")  # gets rid of extra FORTRAN spaes
    ff=int(stuff[i][4]) 
    for item in stuff2: 
        if bb == item: 
        fn.write( str(bb)+','+str("%1.5f" % cc)+','+str("%1.4e" % dd)+','+ee+','+str(ff)+'\n')
```